# How to load env in vite svelte for production

Tags: svelte, vite

So I'm new to Vite and I use it for my svelte app
I really don't understand this part of documentation

During production, these env variables are statically replaced. It is therefore necessary to always reference them using the full static string. For example, dynamic key access like import.meta.env[key] will not work.

I should mention that english is not my first language, and when I try the app on production it showed the env as the baseurl/undefined,
How am I supposed to get the env on production/after the application is build ?
I am currently using

```
import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL
```

to access the env in development,
This is my .env

```
VITE_BASE_URL="secret"
VITE_API_URL="secret/api"
```

I am using cloud run for my production and set the env in the cloud run dashboard. I also use this dockerfile for the production.

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

# copy files and install dependencies
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run run-build
COPY .env.production /app/dist/.env

FROM nginx:1.19
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The issue

The replacement happens in the step

`RUN npm run run-build`

Running this step after the build

`COPY .env.production /app/dist/.env`

does nothing, this .env file is ignored.

#### A solution

Add a step **before** the build step to configure environment variables.

```
COPY .env.production .env
```

Comment: I didn't even realize that the env is supposed to be at the root. thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1):

vite means that it won't be able to understand if you dynamically access env

your syntax is valid and it should work

this is invalid syntax:

```
const key = "VITE_API_URL"
import.meta.env[key]
```

and you don't need to do anything with the file `.env.production` both it will be used in production mode automatically

Comment: So how am I supposed to access the env on production ?, I tried ```import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL``` but it's undefined

Comment: where are you accessing it?  ideally in the script tag