# Environment variables when hosing Vue 3 VITE in Azure App Service

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, vuejs3, vite

I have a Vue 3 app (version 3.2.41) using VITE (version 3.2.2) running on Node (version 16.14) where I'm accessing several environment variables in my .env file.

All my environment variables are prefixed "VITE_" as instructed in the docs:

```
VITE_TEST=Hello
VITE_OTHER=Goodbye
```

And they are access from "import.meta.env":

```
const test = import.meta.env.VITE_TEST;
const other = import.meta.env.VITE_OTHER;
```

I'm hosting by Vue 3 app in Microsoft Azure App Service (Linux). But after relasing the app, the environment values are all blank. They all work fine when running on localhost.

I don't have my ".env" file in Git, it's ignored. So what I have tried is to add these environment variables to the Configuration -> Application Settings, like I would normally do on a .NET 6 web application. But they don't seem to apply at all.

I have tested to prefix my environment variables with "VUE_APP_" like when Vue was not supported by Vite. But those are not accessible.

```
const test = import.meta.env.VUE_APP_TEST;
```

I have also tried to access them like before with "process.env.", but that gives a JavaScript error saying that "process" is undefined.

```
const test = process.env.VITE_TEST;
```

I don't know if there are stuff to change or add in the "vite.config.js" file or in "src/App.vue". So I'm basically stuck and hoping that someone have seen this before that could guide me in the right direction.

I have also tried hosing in a Windows App Service, but that only produce a "404 - Not Found" when trying to access the site after deployment. And Microsoft recommends using a Linux service for Node projects, so that's what I did.

Note: I am not using a Azure Static Web App here, I'm using an App Service.

Comment: In Vite, environment variables are `statically replaced` means their references are replaced with actual values like you have hard coded them. So environment variables should be made available in build step. it wont load anything at runtime.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. It means I would need to have separate builds for all environments.

But thanks, that's good to know. Do you know a good place with example on how they are included in the build yaml file?

Comment: You can refer to their [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#production-replacement) to get started. There is a similar discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74806859/how-to-load-env-in-vite-svelte-for-production). I have not used Vite for my vue 3 projects, so I wont be of much help to you any further than that.

Comment: @MatJ - Will the Vue CLI behave the same way as Vite in the matter of environment variables? Provided that the variables are prefixed "VUE_APP_" and read by "process.env"? Sorry for spamming.

Comment: Yes, Vue CLI acts the same as Vite for environment variables. In fact, most (if not all) SPAs act this way. Think of it this way, your app "runs" once when you're building it and creating static files (js, css, html...). During build time you have context of the environment variables, and those values get embedded into the js code. Now, these values are client visible (that is why you shouldn't put sensitive information there). If you wanted to change it dynamically, you would have to use a server side rendering solution like Nuxt (but, you would have to regenerate static sites to see changes)

Comment: You would eventually run into this problem when working with Docker. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55962511/19656174) covers how to replace it with webpack bundler. Personally, I would create different CI/CD pipelines that create separate deployments for production/development/staging/... or whatever else you might need. You can store environment variables on Github or GitLab securely and match pull requests to their respective branches.

Comment: That's why i like create-react-app for React.. it's really upset to see such tech(vue) which does not support multi-env config at runtime ( not at build time)